# issues with CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I am trying do to what seems to be a simple task but I can't make it work for now. I want to use cloud composer to gather data from a SQL database and save it in GCS. I am having permissions issues

Here is my DAG:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator import CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator
from airflow import models
import datetime

export_body = {
  "exportContext": {
    "kind": "sql#exportContext",
    "fileType": "csv",
    "uri": "gs://mybucket/export_sql.csv",
    "csvExportOptions": {
      "selectQuery": "select count(*) as number from some_table"
    }
  }
}

yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today(),
    datetime.datetime.min.time())

start_date = yesterday

JOB_NAME = "job_name"
default_args = {
    'start_date': start_date,
}


with models.DAG(JOB_NAME,
                schedule_interval="@hourly",
                default_args=default_args) as dag:

    sql_export_task = CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator(body=export_body,
                                                     project_id="project_id",
                                                     instance='instance',
                                                     task_id='sql_export_task')
    sql_export_task
```

I created a specific service account that have some roles:
Cloud SQL Admin
Composer Worker
Storage Object Creator

When I create the environment i specify this account and then I upload the above DAG in the appropriate bucket.

I get this error:

```
  "error": 
    "code": 403
    "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket."
    "errors": 

        "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket."
        "domain": "global"
        "reason": "notAuthorized





Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1491, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator.py", line 643, in execut
    body=self.body
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 247, in inner_wrappe
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_sql_hook.py", line 310, in export_instanc
    'Exporting instance {} failed: {}'.format(instance, ex.content
AirflowException: Exporting instance prod failed: 
  "error": 
    "code": 403
    "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket."
    "errors": 

        "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket."
        "domain": "global"
        "reason": "notAuthorized
```

I thought the Storage Object Creator role should give me permission. 
Should I add an other role to the service account? which one?
Any advice or solution on how to proceed would be most appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I added the Storage Admin role and this removed this error.
However it seems despite that my DAG is not working.

The airflow interface send mixed signals: The task has no status:

[image]

But it is somehow a success ?

[image]

I checked my bucket the csv file I hoped would be created is missing.

Any advice or solution on how to proceed would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into your permission denied issue, glad that you sorted it out.

I was curious as to why the CSV is missing and I'm thinking that [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export#exportContext.databases) might have to do with it.

> If fileType is CSV, you can specify one database, either by using this property or by using the csvExportOptions.selectQuery property, which takes precedence over this property.

When using a CSV you have to specify the DB either by using `exportContext.databases[]` or by specifying it in the query you're doing.

Let me know.

Comment: I added
``` "databases": ["db_name"]``` to the exportContext

And now the permission issue are back :(
In the docs i see: "It is not the service account configured in Airflow that communicates with GCS, but rather the service account of the particular Cloud SQL instance."

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/operator/gcp/sql.html#cloudsqlinstanceexportoperator

so I am looking into that

Comment: Try adding Cloud SQL roles to the service account. Let me know if you run into any other issues and we can look into them.

Comment: the airflow service account is Cloud SQL Admin too i forgot it in the list

Comment: Have you managed to find the correct permissions? Can you give us more info of what is your issue right now?

Comment: As I told you in the first comment, I specified the database. Now the task as a status: "failed". And i have the same error logs as before         "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket."

The documentation suggest that the Cloud SQL instance service account should be allowed to write in GCS, and I am trying to do that.

Comment: I managed to allow the SQL instance to write in my bucket.
The trick is that the SQL instance service account is not available in "IAM & admin>Service accounts" or  "IAM & admin>IAM" where you can set the storage admin role.
You can see the  account in the instance overview.

Comment: In brief, you should follow the next steps to set the storage.admin role to your service account:
1. Go to Cloud Storage [2] and click on the bucket you need.
2. Click on the tab "Permissions", after this you will see a blue button "Add members" click on it.
3. Add the Cloud SQL service account as a "New member" .
4. Select the role "Storage Admin" and save it.